# Can a module provide a default block with editable content? (editable through the standard block interface)

Tags: blocks

I have multiple blocks I'd like to include in a module/install profile; (containing markup) but need to be editable through the standard block UI? What's the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal adds custom blocks in a form submit function using database queries directly, it doesn't expose an API for that particular function unfortunately, so you'll have to write/copy the code manually.

You can find all the code you need in [`block_add_block_form_submit()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.admin.inc/function/block_add_block_form_submit/7).

You insert the custom block into the database like so:

```
$delta = db_insert('block_custom')
  ->fields(array(
    'body' => '<p>Some markup</p>',
    'info' => 'Block description',
    'format' => 'full_html',
  ))
  ->execute();
```

Then you need to make this block available to all installed themes:

```
$query = db_insert('block')->fields(array('visibility', 'pages', 'custom', 'title', 'module', 'theme', 'status', 'weight', 'delta', 'cache'));
foreach (list_themes() as $key => $theme) {
  if ($theme->status) {
    $query->values(array(
      'visibility' => 1, // visible
      'pages' => '', // list of pages 
      'custom' => 1, // This is a custom block
      'title' => 'Block title',
      'module' => 'block', // The block module handles custom modules
      'theme' => $theme->name,
      'status' => 0,
      'weight' => 0,
      'delta' => $delta,
      'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
    ));
  }
}
$query->execute();
```

You'll want to put that code either in `hook_install()`/`hook_enable()` if you plan to do this in a custom module, or `hook_install()` if you're doing it in an install profile.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [block_example.module](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/block_example!block_example.module/7), there it goes like so:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 *   Hello Drupal, here is a new block.
 */
function MYMODULE_block_info() {
  $blocks = array();
  $blocks['configurable_block'] = array(
    'info' => t('My Block\'s name'),
    // Setting the following two values will enable this block on ALL themes.
    // Better place this block manually after module activation. Alternatively
    // you could db_update the theme value programmatically, of course.
    //'status' => TRUE,
    //'region' => 'content',
    'visibility' => BLOCK_VISIBILITY_LISTED,
    'pages' => '<front>',
  );
  return $blocks;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_configure().
 *   To create a configurable block we need to add a form to our block.
 */
function MYMODULE_block_configure($delta = '') {
  $form = array();
  if ($delta == 'configurable_block') {
    $form['MYMODULE_block_content'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Block contents'),
      '#size' => 60,
      '#description' => t('This text will appear in the example block.'),
      '#default_value' => variable_get('MYMODULE_block_content', t('Some example content.')),
    );
  }
  return $form;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_save().
 *   Whenever the block content is edited, it gets stored into the DB.
 */
function MYMODULE_block_save($delta = '', $edit = array()) {
  if ($delta == 'configurable_block') {
    variable_set('MYMODULE_block_content', $edit['MYMODULE_block_content']);
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 *   Tells Drupal what it should put into the block's content.
 */
function MYMODULE_block_view($delta = '') {
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'configurable_block':
      $block['subject'] = '';
      $block['content'] = MYMODULE_block_content($delta);
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}

/**
 * A module-defined block content function.
 */
function MYMODULE_block_content($which_block) {
  switch ($which_block) {
    case 'configurable_block':
      $result = array(
        '#markup' => variable_get('MYMODULE_block_content',
          t('A default value. This block was created at %time',
            array('%time' => date('c'))
          )
        ),
      );
      return $result;
  }
}
```